# Non-orthogonal projections summing to 1 in infinite-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider projection operators $\rho_1,\ldots,\rho_k$ defined on vector space $V$ over field of characteristic $0$, such that
$$
\rho_1+\cdots+\rho_k = 1
$$
Projections $\rho, \pi$ are said to be *orthogonal*, if $\rho\circ\pi=\pi\circ\rho=0$.

**Question:** Are  $\rho_1,\ldots,\rho_k$ necessarily pairwise orthogonal?

If $V$ has finite dimension, the answer is yes. I expect it not to be the case in general, but I can't seem to come up with a counterexample.

**Bonus question:**
What about possibly infinite set of projections, where 
$$
\sum_{\rho\in P} \rho = 1
$$
is understood as "for each $v\in V$, only finitely many of $\rho v$ are nonzero, and their sum is $v$" ?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment what should be improved?

Comment: From these assumptions one can prove $\rho_i \circ (\sum_{j\ne i}\rho_j)=0$. Hence the conclusion is valid for $k=2$.

Comment: @daw Indeed. It holds for $k=3$ as well - if $\rho_1+\rho_2+\rho_3=1$, then $\rho_1+\rho_2 = 1-\rho_3$ is a projection, and one can prove that sum of projections is a projection iff they're orthogonal, hence $\rho_1\perp \rho_2$. Unfortunately, I don't think it generalizes easily.

Comment: Analogous problem on Hilbert space, with orthogonal projections ($p^*=p=p^2$): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/117702/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't true in general, so if we take our space $V=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}_0$ (that mean the space of sequences $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ with finitely nonzero sequences ) and we define the canonical algebraic bases $e_n$ and the projections :
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
P_1(e_n)=\frac{n}{2} (e_n+e_{2-n})\\
P_2(e_n)=\frac{n}{2} (e_n-e_{2-n})\\
P_3(e_n)=\frac{-n}{2} (e_n+e_{-2-n})\\
P_4(e_n)=\frac{-n}{2} (e_n-e_{-2-n})\\
P_5(e_n)=e_n
\end{array}\right.
$$
So you can easily verify that $P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4+P_5=1$  but there are not orthogonal.

Comment: And You can find more detail in this paper :
H. Bart, T. Ehrhardt and B. Silbermann ''ZERO SUMS OF IDEMPOTENTS IN BANACH ALGEBRAS'' Integr Equat Oper Th 
Vol. 19 (1994) pp 125-134

Comment: no but the space of all sequences

Comment: oh yes yes you are right i need to change the word basis or taking the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ of finitely nonzero sequences.

Comment: Thank you - it's a pleasant surprise to get an answer after few months!