# Prove that for a set of self-adjoint projectors on a Hilbert space, $\sum_k P_k$ is a projection iff $P_i P_j=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, projection

It is known that a projection operator can be written explicitly as follows:

$$\hat{P} = \sum_{k=1}^n \hat{P_k} = \sum_{k=1}^n | k \rangle\langle k|$$

where $\{|k\rangle$, $k= 1,\ldots,n\}$ are the orthonormal basis.

So it is curious to ask if a projection should always be written as the sum of projection operators to the smaller subspaces, which are orthogonal to each other. This is proved as following.

Given two projection operators $\hat{P_1}$ and $\hat{P_2}$, for the sum $\hat{P} = \hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2}$ to be also a projection operator:

$$(\hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2})^2 = \hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2} \\
 \Rightarrow \hat{P_1}^2 + \hat{P_2}^2 + \hat{P_1}\hat{P_2}
 + \hat{P_2}\hat{P_1} \\
= \hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2} + \hat{P_1}\hat{P_2} + \hat{P_2}\hat{P_1} = \hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2}$$

Therefore we get

$$\hat{P_1}\hat{P_2} + \hat{P_2}\hat{P_1}\tag 1 = 0$$

(1) left-multiplied by $\hat{P_1}$, we get:

$$\hat{P_1}\hat{P_2} + \hat{P_1}\hat{P_2}\hat{P_1} = 0\tag 2$$

(1) right-multiplied by $\hat{P_1}$, we get:

$$\hat{P_1}\hat{P_2}\hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2}\hat{P_1} = 0\tag3$$

(2) - (3) gives:

$$\hat{P_1}\hat{P_2} - \hat{P_2}\hat{P_1} = 0\tag4$$

(1) + (4) eventually gives:

$$\hat{P_1}\hat{P_2} = \hat{P_2}\hat{P_1} = 0\tag5$$

The above proved that equation (5) is the necessary condition for the sum $\hat{P} = \hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2}$ to be also a projection operator. It is straightforward to see that (5) is the sufficient condition, too. So we conclude that:

$$(\hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2})^2 = \hat{P_1} + \hat{P_2} \\
\Longleftrightarrow \hat{P_1}\hat{P_2} = \hat{P_2}\hat{P_1} = 0$$

given two projection operators $\hat{P_1}$ and $\hat{P_2}$.

My question is: what is the general theory/theorem that formally addressed the above question and stated the above result?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know the reason for the convention you're using of putting hats on all the projections?  Is that a way to distinguish operators from other objects?

Comment: I've brought this question much closer to standard MathJax usage conventions.

Comment: @JonasMeyer from my understanding, yes, it is a way to distinguish operators from other objects.

Comment: related to [Problem with sum of projections](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507796/173147)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Orthogonal projections with $\sum P_i =I$, proving that $i\ne j \Rightarrow  P_{j}P_{i}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117702/orthogonal-projections-with-sum-p-i-i-proving-that-i-ne-j-rightarrow-p)

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward generalization of your result is that if $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$ are self-adjoint projections on a Hilbert space, then $P_1+P_2+\cdots+P_n$ is a projection if and only if $P_iP_j=0$ for $i\neq j$.  In an abstract formulation of the same result, we would say that the $P_i$s are projections in a C*-algebra (i.e., self-adjoint idempotent elements).  It is equivalent because every C*-algebra is *-isomorphic to an algebra of operators on Hilbert space.

A proof of the nontrivial implication is the subject of the question [Sums of projections in a C*-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117632/sums-of-projections-in-a-c-algebra?lq=1).

A special case, where the operators sum to the identity, is the subject of the question
[Orthogonal projections with $\sum P_i =I$, proving that $i\ne j \Rightarrow  P_{j}P_{i}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117702/orthogonal-projections-with-sum-p-i-i-proving-that-i-ne-j-rightarrow-p).

And in the nonselfadjoint case, the result need not be true, as seen in the question
[Non-orthogonal projections summing to 1 in infinite-dimensional space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848873/non-orthogonal-projections-summing-to-1-in-infinite-dimensional-space?lq=1).

However, on a finite dimensional space, the special case where they sum to the identity is still true even without selfadjointness, as seen in the question [Multiplication of two projection operator is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477937/).

As you have shown, by not using selfadjointness or finite-dimensionality, the $n=2$ case depends only on idempotency.

Comment: Thanks for the great list of various generalization cases! For n > 2 on a Hilbert space, how should I intuitively (or geometrically) understand the self-adjointness of a projection operator: $\hat{P}^\dagger = \hat{P}$? If I think of a finite-dimensional space, all I could see is that means a symmetric matrix operation.

Comment: @WishBeLeibniz: In general, corresponding to an idempotent operator $A$ on a vector space $V$ is a decomposition of $V$ into a direct sum of subspaces, $V=V_1\oplus V_2$, such that each $v\in V$ has a unique representation of the form $v=v_1+v_2$ with $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$, and such that $A(v) = A(v_1+v_2) = v_1$.  It is said that $A$ is the projection onto $V_1$ along $V_2$.  The subspace $V_1$ is the range of $A$, but corresponding to a given subspace, there are many projections having the same range, with many possible $V_2$s.  (to be continued in next comment)

Comment: (continued) However, if $V$ is a Hilbert space, there is a unique *orthogonal* projection onto $V_1$, and this corresponds to the decomposition $V = V_1 \oplus V_1^\perp$, i.e., where $V_2=V_1^\perp$ is the set of vectors orthogonal to everything in $V_1$.  For an idempotent (and bounded) operator on Hilbert space, being self-adjoint is equivalent to being an orthogonal projection.

Comment: (I should have said that $V_1$ is a *closed* subspace, when talking about the orthogonal projection onto $V_1$ in a Hilbert space.)