# Prove that orthogonal projections in a Hilbert space satisfy $pq=0$ iff $p+q\le I$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection

Assume that $p$ and $q$ are (orthogonal) projections on Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. I want to prove:  **$pq=0$ iff $p+q\leq1$**

I had the following in mind: Assume $pq=0$. Then $qp=0$, hence $p+q$ is a projection. One has the theorem that if e and f are two projections, then $e\leq f$ iff $ef=f$. But if we take $e=p+q$ and $f=1$, then $p+q\leq p+q$ which is true. Hence $p+q<1$.

For the other direction I thought about an estimate of $||pqx||$, but I don't know how to go further. Anyone who can help me with this? Furthermore, if there are any corrections about the other directions proof, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The assumption $p+q\le 1$ is equivalent to 
  $$ \forall x\in\mathcal{H},\qquad<(p+q)x,x>\le \Vert x\Vert^2$$
  or equivalently
  $$ \forall x\in\mathcal{H},\qquad \Vert p (x)\Vert^2+\Vert q(x)\Vert^2\le \Vert x\Vert^2$$
  Applying this to $x=q(y)$ we get
  $$ \forall y\in\mathcal{H},\qquad \Vert p (q(y))\Vert^2+\Vert q(y)\Vert^2\le \Vert q(y)\Vert^2$$
  That is $pq(y)=0$ for all $y\in\mathcal{H}$ This proves the missing direction.
- For the first direction we need to show that $e=p+q$ is an orthogonal projection which is easy since clearly $e^*=e$ and as you have shown $e^2=e$ because $pq=qp=0$. Now every orthogonal projection $e$ satisfies $e\le 1$.
  Indeed since for every $x$ the vectors $e(x)$ and $(1-e)(x)$ are orthogonal we have
  $$\Vert x\Vert^2= \Vert e(x)\Vert^2+\Vert (1-e)(x)\Vert^2\ge \Vert e(x)\Vert^2$$
  that is $<e(x),x>\,=\,<e(x),e(x)>\le <x,x>$ for every $x\in\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: what is the reason that every projection is lower or equal the identity?

Comment: @IsidoraBernardita, I added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to prove this, similar to the method used for example [in this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1742922/173147):

1. Suppose $pq=0$. Then $(p+q)^2=p+q$, hence $P\equiv p+q$ is a projection as well. Projections can only have $0$ and $1$ as eigenvalues (e.g. because their minimal polynomial is $x\mapsto x(1-x)$), thus $\langle x,Px\rangle\le1$ for all $x$, that is, $P\le I$.
2. Suppose now $p+q\le I$. Then $p\le I- q$. Multiplying by $q$ on left *and* right, this becomes $qpq\le q(I-q)q=0$. But $qpq=qppq=(qp)(qp)^\dagger\ge0$, hence $qpq=0$ and $qp=pq=0$.